# Xml Subchild node appears outside of child node during an insert via a Gridview Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

My webpage consist of a GridView control with insert/update/delete functionality; it's data is stored in an XML file. The problem am facing is that when I insert a new row, the **subchild node (the newly inserted date) appears outside of it's child node (**the pos node)** when copied over into the xml file: e.g:

```
<root>
  <pos>
    <partNumbers>
      <partid>0</partid>
      <partnumber>796547</partnumber>
    </partNumbers>
    <partNumbers>
      <partid>3</partid>
      <partnumber>567890</partnumber>
    </partNumbers>
  </pos>
  <partNumbers>
    <partid>10</partid>
    <partnumber>129123</partnumber>
  </partNumbers>
</root>
```

...what I'm aiming for is to have the newly inserted row(s) to remain within the  node as shown below:

```
<root>
      <pos>
        <partNumbers>
          <partid>0</partid>
          <partnumber>796547</partnumber>
        </partNumbers>
        <partNumbers>
          <partid>3</partid>
          <partnumber>567890</partnumber>
        </partNumbers>
         <partNumbers>
        <partid>10</partid>
        <partnumber>129123</partnumber>
      </partNumbers>
      </pos>
     </root>
```

The following is my insert code:

```
protected void gvPartNumber_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "insertXMLData")
        {
            string partid = ((TextBox)gvPartNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPartIDInsert")).Text;
            string partnumber = ((TextBox)gvPartNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPartNumberInsert")).Text;
            BindGridView();
            DataTable dtXMLInsert = (DataTable)gvPartNumber.DataSource;

            DataSet dsgvPartNumber = new DataSet();
            dsgvPartNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
            DataRow drInsert = dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"].NewRow();
            drInsert["partid"] = partid;
            drInsert["partnumber"] = partnumber;
            dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"].Rows.Add(drInsert);
            dsgvPartNumber.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
            BindGridView();

        }
      }
```

Could I please gets some direction as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this but based on the fact that it's adding the XML under the root, I would *guess* that the following line needs to change:

```
dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"].Rows.Add(drInsert);
```

to

```
dsgvPartNumber.Tables["pos"].Rows.Add(drInsert);
```

Edit:

Here we go:

add:

```
DataRow drParent = dsgvPartNumber.Tables["pos"].Rows[0];
drInsert.SetParentRow(drParent);
```

final code should read:

```
DataSet dsgvPartNumber = new DataSet();
dsgvPartNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
DataRow drInsert = dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"].NewRow();
drInsert["partid"] = partid;
drInsert["partnumber"] = partnumber;
DataRow drParent = dsgvPartNumber.Tables["pos"].Rows[0];
drInsert.SetParentRow(drParent);
dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"].Rows.Add(drInsert);
dsgvPartNumber.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
BindGridView();
```

Comment: ...That was my first assumption as well, but the following error is generated: Column 'partid' does not belong to table pos. I will continue to work w/ the code to obtain a solution, but please let me know if anything else comes to mind. Thank you.